# Не работает php на LAMP

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

Установил LAMP на ubuntu 14.04. Все встало хорошо. "Привет, мир!" выводит спокойно. Но когда ставлю сайт, подключаю к бд, то выводит такое.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите пожалуйста, а то уже второй день сижу с этим.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

Скорей всего у Вас отключено использование коротких тегов `"<?"`.

Проверьте, какие теги используются в файлах php сайта.

И, или включите поддержку коротких тегов или исправьте `"<?"` на `"<?php"`